# Resolve conflicting package resource declarations

Tags: puppet

We are attempting to use the [camptocamp/puppet-nagios](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-nagios) module, but we're running into a packaging naming conflict between vanilla CentOS repositories and [RPMForge/RepoForge](http://repoforge.org/). The `nsca` daemon in CentOS provides the same service as the `nagios-nsca` package in RepoForge. In attempt to install the RepoForge package yet satisify the `Package` requirement for `nsca` resource, I've added this to my node definition:

```
    include ::nagios
    package { 'nagios-nsca': ensure => installed, alias => 'nsca', }
    include ::nagios::nsca::server
```

The resulting error is:

```
    Error: Duplicate declaration: Package[nsca] is already declared in
    file /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-0/role/manifests/nagios.pp:45;
    cannot redeclare at
    /tmp/vagrant-puppet-1/modules-2/nagios/manifests/nsca/server.pp:24
```

The next test was to use order and calling the `class` directly from the node:

```
    include ::nagios
    package { 'nagios-nsca': ensure => installed, alias => 'nsca', } -> 
    class {'::nagios::nsca::server' : }
```

The code in question inside the `nagios/manifests/nsca/server.pp` file is:

```
    class nagios::nsca::server(
      $decryption_method = pick($nagios_nsca_decryption_method, '0'),
    ) {

      include ::nagios::params

      # variables used in ERB template
      $basename = $nagios::params::basename

      if !defined (Package['nsca']) {
        package {'nsca':
          ensure => installed;
        }
      }
```

Any insight as to what's happening here? I can always fork the `camptocamp/puppet-nagios` code  and force the behavior we want, but I'd rather not.

Comment: You added the `alias => 'nsca'` to the `package { "nagios-nsca" }` in your node? Why the alias? I suspect that is what's tripping you up.

Comment: I want to satisfy the dependency upon the 'nsca' package by installing 'nagios-nsca'. The package 'nsca' does not exist when pulling from RepoForge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to `! defined(Package['title'])` not working as expected. I fixed this by giving `nagios::nsca::server` an additional parameter of `nsca_package`, including a default value of `nsca` to preserve current behavior:

```
    --- a/manifests/nsca/server.pp
    +++ b/manifests/nsca/server.pp
    @@ -11,6 +11,7 @@
     #
     class nagios::nsca::server(
       $decryption_method = pick($nagios_nsca_decryption_method, '0'),
    +  $nsca_package = 'nsca'
     ) {

       include ::nagios::params
    @@ -20,6 +21,7 @@ class nagios::nsca::server(

       if !defined (Package['nsca']) {
         package {'nsca':
    +      name => $nsca_package,
           ensure => installed;
         }
       }
```

Use for this new parameter would be:

```
    node 'my-nagios-server.local' {
      include ::nagios
      class {'::nagios::nsca::server': nsca_package => 'nagios-nsca', }
    }
```

Comment: Aaaah, right. That construct is evil. We're on the verge of deprecating the defined() function altogether, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/puppet-dev/dkdXaUt8yDg/EwvdHFB-8cUJ Good thinking with the parameter!